# Conflicting declarations of enum

Tags: c++, enums, header

I have a header file called `custom_types.h` that was working fine until now. I have a few enums declared in it and there is no implementation file with the same name.

These are the two declarations in the file:

```
enum playback_type {
    NOTE_PB,
    SONG_PB
};

enum note_name {
    C_REG = 1,
    C_SHARP = 2,
    D_REG = 3
};
```

Now for some reason I'm getting `conflicting declaration errors` ([full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9flA.png)):
[image]

You guys have any idea why this is happening? I don't understand how a single definition can be conflicting.

Comment: Is the header being included more than once?

Comment: Do you have #include guards in your header file?

Comment: I thought I hade the guards but I didn't. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use guards:

```
//custom_types.h

#ifndef custom_types_h  //this is called guard!
#define custom_types_h   

enum playback_type {
    NOTE_PB,
    SONG_PB
};

enum note_name {
    C_REG = 1,
    C_SHARP = 2,
    D_REG = 3
};

#endif  //dont forget this line!
```

Such guards ensure that the *content* of the header file will be included once in one translation unit (TU).

If your compiler supports (modern compilers support this), you could use `#pragma once` as:

```
//custom_types.h

#pragma once  //it ensures that the content of this header will be 
              //included once in one translation unit

enum playback_type {
    NOTE_PB,
    SONG_PB
};

enum note_name {
    C_REG = 1,
    C_SHARP = 2,
    D_REG = 3
};
```

Comment: Well actually they still get included, but the contents within the guard just gets ignored.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Alright. I edited my answer, improving the wordings.

Answer (score 2):

Since headers are full of declarations, you must make sure the compiler doesn't read them twice. Once solution would be to make sure each header is included (directly or through another header) only once. This is not so easy.

The common solution is to add guards:

```
#ifndef SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN
#define SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN

... header contents ...

#endif
```

If this header gets included multiple times, the compiler will see both copies, but will discard the second one, since that `SOME_CONSTANT...` is already defined. That is, this:

```
#include "your_file.h"
...
#include "your_file.h"
```

will become:

```
#ifndef SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN         // not defined
#define SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN         // define it

... header contents ...                              // read these

#endif

...

#ifndef SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN         // already defined
#define SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_WONT_GET_MISTAKEN         // skip

... header contents ...                              // skip

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely you are including the file more than once, that is the same #include in several other .h or .c/.cpp
The easiest way to solve this is to have at the beginning of every .h file a #ifndef that avoids redefinition when the file has already been included through another inclusion path.